# _OBJC_CLASS_$_ShellTask error on objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ShellTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PhoneLocator.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Architectures of my target is `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`

I have checked online throughout day :(. But I didn't get any solution. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your deployment target? iOS? macOS? Seems you are mixing them up somehow ... meaning error looks as if you are trying to run macOS code on iOS.

Comment: for macOS. nope I am running macOS code in macOS

Comment: Ok - where do you define ShellTask? Are you sure that file is included in the project?Check its target membership specifically to make sure it is part of the project.

Comment: inside initialization after that i called getIPAndMacAddress method where I wrote this line     NSString *localIpAddress = [ShellTask executeShellCommand:primaryIPAddress ipAddress:secondaryIPAddress];

Comment: Ok ... lets try to solve it here ... how about you post some of that code ... I don't know ```ShellTask``` ... where does it come from?

Comment: it's properly linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_OBJC_CLASS_$_ShellTask` this error means `ShellTask` this the file name. When you getting these sort of error it means that the file is missing under your `compile sources`. Just add that file the error will be gone

```
In target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources I had all .m files including those that were giving issue.
```